# PHP table, to add, remove and edit rows

Tags: php, html, css, html-table

I have issues with my table, I cannot use Javascript (which I know would be easier). I can only use HTML, PHP and CSS. This is my code that I currently have. The issues I need to resolve are the following:

- I am able to add rows, delete and I am so also able to edit them by using the "contenteditable", however my issue is that every time I add a row or remove one, it refreshes the whole page. How can I fix this issue?
- Also if there is a way to have an edit button instead of my conteneditable method.

Here is my code:

```css
input {
        display: block;   /* makes one <input> per line */
        width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<?php
   if( isset( $_REQUEST["btnadd"]) == "ADD") {
       // add 1 to the row counter
       if (isset($_REQUEST['count'])) $count = $_REQUEST['count'] + 1;
       // set value for first load
       else $count = 1;
   }

   if( isset( $_REQUEST["btnremove"]) == "REMOVE") {
   // decrement the row counter
       $count = $_REQUEST['count'] - 1;
       // set minimum row number
       if ($count < 1) $count = 1;
   }
?>
<form name="form1">
   <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover text-center" align='center'>
       <tr>
           <th align="center">Name</th>
           <th>Start </th>
           <th>Size</th>
           <th>First Condition</th>
           <th>Second Conditon</th>
           <th><input type="submit" name="btnadd" id="btnadd" value="ADD" align='center'></th>
       </tr>
<?php
// print $count rows
for ($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++) {
echo ' <tr>
          <td contenteditable="true"></td>
          <td contenteditable="true"></td>
          <td contenteditable="true"></td>
          <td contenteditable="true"></td>
          <td contenteditable="true"></td>
          <td> <input type="submit" name="btnremove" id="btnremove" value="REMOVE"></td>
      </tr>
';
}
?>
   </table>
   <input type="hidden" name="count" value="<?php echo $count; ?>">
</form>
```

Comment: That's exactly what `input type="submit"` is *supposed* to do. PHP can only make changes to a page server-side. The only way to get what you is, you guessed it, use JavaScript.

Comment: I just changed from <input type="submit"> to button and it still does the same thing. Do you have any ideas on what I can do next? i have been looking everywhere on how to do this without js :(

Comment: `<button type="submit">`s are almost the same as `<input type="submit">`... As @Blazemonger suggests, this isn't something that can be done purely with PHP and HTML, unfortunately. "PHP can only make changes to a page server-side," in other words, anything that PHP `echo`es cannot be changed afterward, like what you have said out loud cannot be altered afterward. You are seeing what PHP already `echo`ed, which can't be changed unless you use javascript :(

Comment: Unfortunately that makes sense :( Thank you for the explanation

Comment: Why can't you use JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

> every time I add a row or remove one, it refreshes the whole page. How can I fix this issue?

Without Javascript you can't.

> if there is a way to have an edit button instead of my conteneditable method

It's rather hard to suggest what your code should be since you don't ofer a description of what the code is intended to do, other than the code which doesn't do what you want. I think you mean something like:

```
<?php
$width=5;
$data=isset($_REQUEST['data']) ? $_REQUEST['data'] : array();
$count=count($data);
if (isset($_REQUEST['delete'])) {
  foreach ($_REQUEST['delete'] as $i) {
    unset($data[$i]);
  }
}
$data=array_values($data);
if( isset( $_REQUEST["btnadd"]) == "ADD") {
   // add 1 to the row counter
   $data[]=array();
}
...
foreach ($data as $i=>$row) {
   print "<tr>\n";
   for ($x=0; $x<$width; $x++) {
      @print "<td><input type='text' name='data[$i][$x]'></td>\n";
   }
   print "<td><input type='checkbox' name='delete[]' value='$i'>";
   print "</tr>\n";
}
print "<tr>
 <td colspan='$width'>
 <input type="submit" name="btnadd" id="btnadd" value="Add">
 </td>
 </tr>\n";
```